# Do Collective Restraint and Nylea's Presence work together in a non-5-color EDH deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Say I have a four-color commander deck that includes blue and green. I have a [Collective Restraint](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCollective%20Restraint%5d) on the field and I cast [Nylea's Presence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNylea%27s%5d%2b%5bPresence%5d) on one of my lands. Do my opponents need to pay 5 to attack me now, even though my deck is missing a color of mana?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Since Nylea's Presence turns the enchanted land into every basic land type, it means that you have all basic land types under your control. Whether you could have originally have them or not doesn't matter to either continuous effect of your enchantments.

Here's a ruling that supports this:

> **2/1/2009:** A number of nonbasic lands have basic land types. Domain abilities don't count the number of lands you control — they count the number of basic land types among lands you control, even if that means checking the same land twice. For example, if you control a Tundra, an Overgrown Tomb, and a Madblind Mountain, you'll have a Plains, Island, Swamp, Mountain, and Forest among the lands you control. Your domain abilities will be maxed out.

This doesn't refer specifically to your question, but as you can see, since your enchanted land will have every basic land type, Collective Restraint's ability will consider it as being a Forest Mountain Swamp Island Plains land.

Comment: See comment above.

Comment: That rule about colored mana has been dropped in January 2016, if I recall correctly. Also, the colors of mana generated by a land do not influence whether a land has a basic land type or not, so it wouldn’t be relevant to your question.

Comment: Domain effects which actually wanted you to have "one of each" would need to be phrased in some very convoluted way. Something along the lines of "For each basic land type, select up to one land you control which has that land type. X is the number of selected lands."

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

[Nylea's Presence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNylea%27s%5d%2b%5bPresence%5d) doesn't care about your Commander's color identity or what kind of lands you have in your deck. It grants all five basic land types.

[Collective Restraint](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCollective%20Restraint%5d) doesn't care about your Commander's color identity, what kind of lands you have in your deck, or what color of mana the abilities of your lands produce (if they produce mana at all). It only counts the number of different basic land types among the lands you control (five).

Comment: I understand how each of them separately work; I was specifically asking about the context in EDH, since I believe if a land would produce an amount of mana of a type not in your commander's color identity, it produces colorless mana of the same amount instead. I was wondering if that affected the situation.

Comment: The rule that turned out-of-commander mana colorless was dropped back when OGW came out and made colorless costs a thing, but even with that rule the answer would be the same

Comment: Re "*it produces colorless mana of the same amount instead*", Neither of those cards care about the color of the mana produced by the land. They don't even care if the lands produce mana. Added this to my answer.